# Saving entity with composite key get ConversionNotSupportedException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use spring boot 2 and some of my entities have composite key

When I try to save an entity, I get this error

> Failed to convert request element:
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type
>   'com.lcm.model.SamplingsPK' for property 'sampling'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'com.lcm.model.SamplingsPK' for
>   property 'sampling': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I get my entity with that method

```
public Samples findById(Integer id, int year, String sampleLetter) {
    Optional<Samples> optSamples = samplesRepository.findById(new SamplesPK(new SamplingsPK(year, id), sampleLetter));

    if (optSamples.isPresent()) {
        return optSamples.get();
    }

    return null;
}


Samples samples = samplesService.findById(idSeq, year, samplesLetter);

Compressions compressionTest = null;

if (samples.getTestSamples().getAbsorptionTest() != null) {
    compressionTest = samples.getTestSamples().getCompressionTest();
} else {
    compressionTest = new Compressions();
}

samplesService.save(samples);
```

My entity

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SamplesPK.class)
public class Samples extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    private String sampleLetter;

    @Embedded
    private TestSamples testSamples;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")})
    private Samplings sampling;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(SamplingsPK.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {
    @Id
    private Integer year;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sampling", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Samples> samples = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class SamplingsPK implements Serializable {

    private int year;

    private Integer id;

    public SamplingsPK(int year, Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.year = year;
    }
}

public class SamplesPK implements Serializable {

    private SamplingsPK sampling;

    private String sampleLetter;

    public SamplesPK(SamplingsPK sampling, String sampleLetter) {
        this.sampling = sampling;
        this.sampleLetter = sampleLetter;
    }
}
```

edit

no problem to save sample, when I pass from sampling

Comment: Running into the same issue. I found that you can persist the entities correctly if you use the EntityManager directly. In the meantime, I've opened https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1391

Comment: not sure because i can create a samplings and a samples... but can save a samples with compression...

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that since the IDs are set manually and there's no `@Version` property on these entities then Spring Data has no good way of knowing if the entity is a brand new one or an existing one. In this case it decides it is an existing entity and attempts a `merge` instead of a `persist`. This is obviously a wrong conclusion.

You can read more about how Spring Data decides if an entity is new or not [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies).

The best solution I've found is to always let entity classes with manually set IDs implement [Persistable interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html). This solves the problem. I make this a rule for myself for any such case. Most of the time I do not have to implement `Persistable`  because my entity either has an auto-generated key or my entity uses a "@Version" annotation. But this is special case.

So, as per the recommendation in the Spring official documentation, for example the `Samplings` class would become:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(SamplingsPK.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings implements Persistable<SamplingsPK> {
    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true; 

    @Id
    private Integer year;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sampling", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Samples> samples = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew; 
    }

    @PrePersist 
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }

    @Override
    public SamplingsPK getId() {
        return new SamplingsPK(year, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had similar issue as OP. Resolved it with this solution. Thanks @peterh. I feel this should be the accepted answer if it solved OP problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1391 and has to do with the use of `@Id @ManyToOne` inside of `Samples`. As a workaround, you can try creating a constructor for `Samplings` that takes in its two primary keys, or maybe one that takes a `java.lang.Integer`? That's what worked for a single level of composite primary keys, but it might not work if you have multiple levels.

You also have `year` in `SamplingsPK` typed as an `int` rather than an `Integer`. This may cause problems with PK recognition, since special consideration is needed to handle autobox-able primitive classes and I doubt it was considered.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too. It does not happen on my IDE on Windows but it happens on the Azure build server

I was on `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.4.5:compile`.

I upgraded the BOM to `<spring-data-bom.version>2020.0.15</spring-data-bom.version>` so I have `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.4.15:compile`

Once I did that it started working correctly.