# Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type entity: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I using Spring Boot to build Restful API. Anything work so good. But, when i try create new Discuss by POST request in Postman. I've received error:
*`"Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.nd2.assignwork.entity.UserAccountEntity' for property 'discussUser'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.nd2.assignwork.entity.UserAccountEntity' for property 'discussUser': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"`*.

---

UserAccountEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserAccount")
public class UserAccountEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_ID", columnDefinition = "varchar(20)")
    private String userID;

    @Column(name = "User_UserName", columnDefinition = "varchar(30)")
    @NotBlank
    private String userUserName;

    @Column(name = "User_FullName", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    @NotBlank
    private String userFullName;

    @Column(name = "User_Password", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
    @NotBlank
    private String userPassword;

    @Column(name = "User_Phone", columnDefinition = "varchar(12)")
    @NotBlank
    private String userPhone;

    @Column(name = "User_Email", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
    @NotBlank
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name = "User_Image", columnDefinition = "varbinary(60000)")
    private byte[] userImage;

    @Column(name = "User_isActive", columnDefinition = "bit default 1")
    private Boolean userIsActive;

    // Foreign key User_Position
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "User_Position")
    @NotNull
    private PositionEntity userPosition;

    // Foreign key User_Department
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "User_Department")
    @NotNull
    private DepartmentEntity userDepartment;

    // Foreign key Task_Personal_Send
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taskPersonalSend")
    private List<TaskEntity> taskPersonalSend = new ArrayList<>();

    // Foreign key Task_Personal_Receive
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taskPersonalReceive")
    private List<TaskEntity> taskPersonalReceive = new ArrayList<>();

    // Foreign key Department_Head
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "departmentHead")
    private DepartmentEntity Department;

    // Foreign key Discuss_User
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "discussUser")
    private List<DiscussEntity> Discuss = new ArrayList<>();

    // Foreign key User_Permission
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Permission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Permission_ID"))
    private Set<PermissionEntity> Permission = new HashSet<>();

    // Foreign key Document_Incomming_UserSend
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "documentIncommingUserSend")
    private List<DocumentIncommingEntity> documentIncommingUserSend = new ArrayList<>();

    // Foreign key Document_Incomming_UserReceive
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "documentIncommingUserReceive")
    private List<DocumentIncommingEntity> documentIncommingUserReceive = new ArrayList<>();

    // Foreign key Document_Send_UserSend
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "documentSendUserSend")
    private List<DocumentSendEntity> documentSendUserSend = new ArrayList<>();

    // Foreign key User_Receive_Document
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Receive_Document", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Document_Send_ID"))
    private Set<DocumentSendEntity> documentSend = new HashSet<>();
}
```

---

UserAccountRepository.java

```
    public interface UserAccountRepository extends JpaRepository<UserAccountEntity, String> {

        // Find single UserAccount by User_UserName
        UserAccountEntity findOneByUserUserName(String userUserName);
    }
```

---

TaskEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")
public class TaskEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Task_ID", columnDefinition = "varchar(20)")
    private String taskID;

    @Column(name = "Task_Title", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    @NotBlank
    private String taskTitle;

    @Column(name = "Task_Content", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    private String taskContent;

    @Column(name = "Task_DateSend", columnDefinition = "datetime")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date taskDateSend;

    @Column(name = "Task_DateEnd", columnDefinition = "datetime")
    private Date taskDateEnd;

    @Column(name = "Task_State", columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int taskState;

    // Foreign key Task_Category_Task
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Task_Category")
    @NotNull
    private TaskCategoryEntity taskCategory;

    // Foreign key Task_Personal_Send
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Task_Personal_Send")
    @NotNull
    private UserAccountEntity taskPersonalSend;

    // Foreign key Task_Personal_Receive
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Task_Personal_Receive")
    @NotNull
    private UserAccountEntity taskPersonalReceive;

    // Foreign key Discuss_Task
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "discussTask")
    private List<DiscussEntity> Discuss = new ArrayList<>();

    // Foreign key Task_File
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Task")
    private Set<FileEntity> File = new HashSet<>();
}
```

---

DiscussEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Discuss")
@IdClass(DiscussID.class)
public class DiscussEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Foreign key Discuss_Task
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Discuss_Task")
    @NotNull
    private TaskEntity discussTask;

    // Foreign key Discuss_User
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Discuss_User")
    @NotNull
    private UserAccountEntity discussUser;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Discuss_Time", columnDefinition = "datetime")
    private Date discussTime;
    
    @Column(name = "Discuss_Content", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    @NotBlank
    private String discussContent;
}
```

---

DiscussId.java

```
public class DiscussID implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private TaskEntity discussTask;
    private UserAccountEntity discussUser;
    private Date discussTime;
}
```

---

DiscussDTO.java

```
public class DiscussDTO {

    private String discussTask;
    private String discussUser;
    private Date discussTime;
    private String discussContent;
}
```

---

DiscussConverter.java

```
@Component
public class DiscussConverter {

    // Convert from DTO to Entity
    public DiscussEntity toEntity(DiscussDTO dto) {
        DiscussEntity entity = new DiscussEntity();
        entity.setDiscussTime(dto.getDiscussTime());
        entity.setDiscussContent(dto.getDiscussContent());
        return entity;
    }
    
    // Convert from Entity to DTO
    public DiscussDTO toDTO(DiscussEntity entity) {
        DiscussDTO dto = new DiscussDTO();
        dto.setDiscussTime(entity.getDiscussTime());
        dto.setDiscussContent(entity.getDiscussContent());
        if(entity.getDiscussTask() != null) {
            dto.setDiscussTask(entity.getDiscussTask().getTaskTitle());
        }
        if(entity.getDiscussUser() != null) {
            dto.setDiscussUser(entity.getDiscussUser().getUserFullName());
        }
        return dto;
    }
    
    // Save update Discuss by convert from DTO to Entity
    public DiscussEntity toEntity(DiscussDTO dto, DiscussEntity entity) {
        if(dto.getDiscussTime() != null) {
            entity.setDiscussTime(dto.getDiscussTime());
        }
        if(dto.getDiscussContent() != null) {
            entity.setDiscussContent(dto.getDiscussContent());
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

---

DiscussRepository.java

```
public interface DiscussRepository extends JpaRepository<DiscussEntity, DiscussID> {

    DiscussEntity findOneByDiscussTask(String discussTask);
    
    DiscussEntity findOneByDiscussUser(String discussUser);
    
    DiscussEntity findOneByDiscussTime(Date discussTime);
    
    void deleteByDiscussTime(Date discussTime);
}
```

---

DiscussService.java

```
@Service
public class DiscussService implements IDiscussService {
    
    @Autowired
    private DiscussConverter discussConverter;
    
    @Autowired
    private DiscussRepository discussRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @Override
    public DiscussDTO save(DiscussDTO discussDTO) {
        DiscussEntity discussEntity = new DiscussEntity();

        DiscussEntity oldDiscussEntity = discussRepository.findOneByDiscussTime(discussDTO.getDiscussTime());
        if(oldDiscussEntity != null) {
            discussEntity = discussConverter.toEntity(discussDTO, oldDiscussEntity);
        } else {
            discussEntity = discussConverter.toEntity(discussDTO);
        }
        
        TaskEntity taskEntity = taskRepository.findOneByTaskTitle(discussDTO.getDiscussTask());
        discussEntity.setDiscussTask(taskEntity);
        
        UserAccountEntity userAccountEntity = userAccountRepository.findOneByUserUserName(discussDTO.getDiscussUser());
        discussEntity.setDiscussUser(userAccountEntity);        
        
        discussEntity = discussRepository.save(discussEntity);
        return discussConverter.toDTO(discussEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Date[] ids) {
        for(Date id: ids) {
            discussRepository.deleteByDiscussTime(id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<DiscussDTO> findAll() {
        List<DiscussDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<DiscussEntity> entities = discussRepository.findAll();
        
        for(DiscussEntity entity: entities) {
            DiscussDTO dto = discussConverter.toDTO(entity);
            result.add(dto);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

---

DiscussAPI.java

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class DiscussAPI {

    @Autowired
    private DiscussService discussService;
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/discuss")
    public DiscussOutput showDiscuss() {
        DiscussOutput result = new DiscussOutput();
        result.setListResult(discussService.findAll());
        return result;
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/discuss")
    public DiscussDTO saveDiscuss(@RequestBody DiscussDTO model) {
        return discussService.save(model);
    }
    
    @PutMapping(value = "/api/discuss/{discussTime}")
    public DiscussDTO updateDiscuss(@RequestBody DiscussDTO model, @PathVariable("discussTime") Date discussTime) {
        model.setDiscussTime(discussTime);
        return discussService.save(model);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/api/discuss")
    public void deleteDiscuss(@RequestBody Date[] discussTimes) {
        discussService.delete(discussTimes);
    }
}
```

---

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nd2.assignwork</groupId>
    <artifactId>ND2Assignwork</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.49</mysql.version>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.3.1</jaxb-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

Exception throw

```
 2023-10-19 09:00:19.687  INFO 13488 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-10-19 09:00:20.234  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@41f69e84: startup date [Thu Oct 19 09:00:15 ICT 2023]; root of context hierarchy
2023-10-19 09:00:20.302  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/department],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.DepartmentAPI.deleteDepartment(java.lang.String[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.303  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/department],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DepartmentDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DepartmentAPI.createDepartment(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DepartmentDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.304  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/department/{departmentId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DepartmentDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DepartmentAPI.updateDepartment(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DepartmentDTO,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.304  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/department],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.DepartmentOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.DepartmentAPI.showDepartment()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.305  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/discuss],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DiscussDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DiscussAPI.saveDiscuss(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DiscussDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.305  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/discuss/{discussTime}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DiscussDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DiscussAPI.updateDiscuss(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DiscussDTO,java.util.Date)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.305  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/discuss],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.DiscussAPI.deleteDiscuss(java.util.Date[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.305  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/discuss],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.DiscussOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.DiscussAPI.showDiscuss()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.306  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentincomming/{documentIncommingId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentIncommingDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentIncommingAPI.updateDocumentIncomming(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentIncommingDTO,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.306  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentincomming],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.DocumentIncommingOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentIncommingAPI.showDocumentIncomming()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.307  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentincomming],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentIncommingAPI.deleteDocumentIncomming(java.lang.String[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.307  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentincomming],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentIncommingDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentIncommingAPI.saveDocumentIncomming(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentIncommingDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.308  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentsend],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentSendAPI.deleteDocumentSend(java.lang.String[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.308  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentsend],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.DocumentSendOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentSendAPI.showDocumentSend()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.308  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentsend],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentSendDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentSendAPI.saveDocumentSend(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentSendDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.308  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/documentsend/{documentSendId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentSendDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.DocumentSendAPI.updateDocumentSend(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.DocumentSendDTO,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.311  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}/addDocumentIncomming/{documentIncommingId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.addDocumentIncommingFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.312  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}/deleteDocumentIncomming/{documentIncommingId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.deleteDocumentIncommingFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.312  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}/deleteDocumentSend/{documentSendId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.deleteDocumentSendFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.312  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}/addDocumentSend/{documentSendId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.addDocumentSendFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.312  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.FileDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.createFile(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.FileDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.313  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}/deleteTask/{taskId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.deleteTaskFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.313  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}/addTask/{taskId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.addTaskFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.313  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.deleteFile(java.lang.String[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.313  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.FileOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.showFile()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.313  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.FileDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.getSingleUser(java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.313  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/file/{fileId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.FileDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.FileAPI.updateFile(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.FileDTO,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.314  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/permission],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PermissionDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.PermissionAPI.createPermission(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PermissionDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.315  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/permission/{permissionId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PermissionDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.PermissionAPI.updatePermission(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PermissionDTO,int)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.315  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/permission],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.PermissionAPI.deletePermission(int[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.315  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/permission],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.PermissionOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.PermissionAPI.showPermission()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.316  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/position],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.PositionAPI.deletePosition(int[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.316  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/position],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PositionDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.PositionAPI.createPosition(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PositionDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.316  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/position/{positionId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PositionDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.PositionAPI.updatePosition(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.PositionDTO,int)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.316  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/position],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.PositionOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.PositionAPI.showPosition()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.317  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/task],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskAPI.saveTask(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.318  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/task],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskAPI.deleteTask(java.lang.String[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.318  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/task/{taskId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskAPI.updateTask(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskDTO,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.318  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/task],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.TaskOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskAPI.showTask()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.319  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/taskcategory],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskCategoryAPI.deleteTaskCategory(int[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.319  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/taskcategory/{taskCategoryId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskCategoryDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskCategoryAPI.updateTaskCategory(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskCategoryDTO,int)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.319  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/taskcategory],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.TaskCategoryOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskCategoryAPI.showTaskCategory()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.320  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/taskcategory],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskCategoryDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.TaskCategoryAPI.createTaskCategory(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.TaskCategoryDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.321  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.deleteUserAccount(java.lang.String[])
2023-10-19 09:00:20.321  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount/{userId}/addPermission/{permissionId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.addUserPermission(java.lang.String,int)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.321  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.UserAccountDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.createUserAccount(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.UserAccountDTO)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.321  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount/{userId}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.UserAccountDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.updateUserAccount(com.nd2.assignwork.dto.UserAccountDTO,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.321  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.api.output.UserAccountOutput com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.showUserAccount()
2023-10-19 09:00:20.322  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount/{userId}/deleteDocumentSend/{documentSendId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.deleteUserReceiveDocument(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.322  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount/{userId}/deletePermission/{permissionId}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.deleteUserPermission(java.lang.String,int)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.322  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount/{userId}/addDocumentSend/{documentSendId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.addUserReceiveDocument(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.322  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/useraccount/{userId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.nd2.assignwork.dto.UserAccountDTO com.nd2.assignwork.api.UserAccountAPI.getSingleUser(java.lang.String)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.323  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.324  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.342  INFO 13488 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2023-10-19 09:00:20.342  INFO 13488 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2023-10-19 09:00:20.374  INFO 13488 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2023-10-19 09:00:20.608  INFO 13488 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2023-10-19 09:00:20.643  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8282 (http)
2023-10-19 09:00:20.646  INFO 13488 --- [           main] com.nd2.assignwork.Application           : Started Application in 5.904 seconds (JVM running for 6.241)
2023-10-19 09:00:33.237  INFO 13488 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-10-19 09:00:33.237  INFO 13488 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2023-10-19 09:00:33.256  INFO 13488 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
2023-10-19 09:00:33.430  INFO 13488 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2023-10-19 09:00:33.771  WARN 13488 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.nd2.assignwork.entity.TaskEntity' for property 'discussTask'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.nd2.assignwork.entity.TaskEntity' for property 'discussTask': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I tried many way, but i can't solve it! Anyone can see my entire code, please help me. Thank you!
[This is my GitHub](https://github.com/NguyenLuan11/ND2AssignWork)

Comment: Provide your full stack trace, where is this exception thrown? also, maybe try to share your json body of your post request

Comment: entity classes `UserAccountEntity` and `TaskEntity` don't have @Id attribute. Is this compiling for you?

Comment: The code shown here wouldn't even work, also an `@Id` on a relationship field? Feels like you should either have an `@EmbeddedId` or something else? What does your database structure look like?

Comment: entity classes UserAccountEntity and TaskEntity have @Id attribute, but i dont show it. I want you attend about where are make error.

Comment: I have provided it. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: @LuânNguyên please provide full stacktrace of your exception. Only exception message is not enough

Comment: ok i will provide full

Comment: @M.Deinum my problem in here is don't find User or Task by name when i enter the input, in spite of i have declare it in UserAccountRepository and TaskRepository.

Comment: This code isn't representative of what you have, so anything we will provide will not solve it. Please provide actual code. This wouldn't even compile or work even if we tried.

Comment: @M.Deinum you can see my entire code in GitHub to have more infomation because the post body was overloaded. Please help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide the full stacktrace I can't say it for sure, but from your code maybe you are having some potential issues. In your `DiscussEntity` you are declaring

```java
   @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Discuss_Task")
    @NotNull
    private TaskEntity discussTask;
```

But you are using this method in `DiscussRepository`

```java
    DiscussEntity findOneByDiscussTask(String discussTask);
```

Doesn't make sense since you declared `discussTask` with type `TaskEntity` but you are using in the repository as a `String`.

One quick way to resolve this is to change repository method to:

```java
DiscussEntity findOneByDiscussTask_TaskId(String discussTask);
```

I think this is the cause for the issue you are having, but you'll need to have a look around to see exactly which one cause it.

Comment: I've tried it, but it didn't work. But, thanks for your comment.

Comment: The problem in here is don't find User or Task by name when i enter the input have userUserName and taskTitle in spite of i have declare it in UserAccountRepository and TaskRepository.

Answer (score 0):

Able to replicate the reported issue and found a possible solution. The solution code base can be referred in this [GitHub](https://github.com/vasant-techie/ND2AssignWork-stackoverflow) link.

**Solution:** `com.nd2.assignwork.entity.DiscussEntity` class to implement `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable` interface and override its methods as shown below. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682174/saving-entity-with-composite-key-get-conversionnotsupportedexception).

**NOTE:**

> I have used H2 embedded database and this code base can be directly
> tested without any create-ddl or insert-dml statements. Refer `data.sql`
> file in `src/main/resources` directory which is automatically triggered by Spring
> Boot and no manual effort is needed. The point is, this code is
> ready-to-run. I used primary key of `Task` & `UserAccount` to find instead of `findOneByUserUserName` and `findOneByTaskTitle`. This can be changed to locate userAccount by username & task by title as well. Introduced a new table `DEPARTMENT_USER_MAPPING` (*DepartmentUserEntity.java*) and externalized the User and Department mapping to avoid Circular Reference.

**POST Request - URI: /api/discuss**

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8282/api/discuss' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "discussTime": "2023-10-21",
    "discussContent": "Hello",
    "discussTaskID": "1",
    "discussUserID": "1"
}'
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "discussTaskID": "1",
    "discussUserID": "1",
    "discussTime": 1697846400000,
    "discussContent": "Hello"
}
```

**DiscussEntity.java:**

```
package com.nd2.assignwork.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Discuss")
@IdClass(DiscussID.class)
public class DiscussEntity implements Serializable, Persistable<DiscussID> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true;

    // Foreign key Discuss_Task
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns(
            @JoinColumn(name = "taskID", referencedColumnName = "Task_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    @NotNull
    private TaskEntity discussTask;

    // Foreign key Discuss_User
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns(
            @JoinColumn(name = "userID", referencedColumnName = "User_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    @NotNull
    private UserAccountEntity discussUser;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Discuss_Time", columnDefinition = "datetime")
    private Date discussTime;

    @Column(name = "Discuss_Content", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    @NotBlank
    private String discussContent;

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    @Override
    public DiscussID getId() {
        return new DiscussID(discussTime);
    }

}
```

**Addition to Maven pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.30</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
  <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```